# Why jquery string for cartesian product throwing errors?

Tags: jquery

i'm stucked with one error from a string which I'm making from loop according to the values from dropdowns. here is my code below also instruction with each line:

```
$('.select2-set_attribute_value').on('select2:select', function (e) {
        var row = 1;
        var data = e.params.data;
        id = data.id;
        text = data.text;
        //console.log(id+' '+text);
        
        var child = variantRowAdd(row, id, text);
        $('#variantsRowData').append(child);
        
        var cartesian_str = [];
        $('.select2-set_attribute_value').each(function(index1, value1){
            cartesian_str += '[';
            obj = $( this ).select2('data');
            
            $.each(obj, function(index, value){
                cartesian_str += "'"+value.text+"', ";
            });
            cartesian_str = cartesian_str.substring(0,cartesian_str.lastIndexOf(","));
            cartesian_str += '], ';
        });
        complete_string = cartesian_str.substring(0,cartesian_str.lastIndexOf(","));
            
        const cartesianProduct = (...arr) => {
        return arr.reduce((acc,val) => {
              return acc.map(el => {
                 return val.map(element => {
                    return el.concat([element]);
                 });
              }).reduce((acc,val) => acc.concat(val) ,[]);
           }, [[]]);
        };
        console.log(complete_string);
        var typeofstr = typeof(complete_string);
        console.log(typeofstr);
        console.log(cartesianProduct(['Red', 'Pink', 'Blue'], ['Berry', 'Phalai', 'Malta'])); //Working fine like that
        console.log(cartesianProduct(complete_string)); //Getting error through that
    });
```

Output into console

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you show your select from where values are coming i.e : `select2-set_attribute_value` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying that a string does not have the `map()` function (see Mozilla MDN [string reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)).

You probably want to call `JSON.parse()` before? Why are you building a string instead of an array? Do you need that string later? You can build an array and call `JSON.stringify()` instead, if you need a string.

Reference for JSON parse and stringify: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Comment: hi Perter, thanks for response, As you can see ['Red', 'Pink', 'Blue'], ['Berry', 'Phalai', 'Malta'] this object is working fine print results into console. The loop is building up string. is there a way to convert string into object. I know JSON.parse() will do it but it's throwing error on multi-dimentional objects. It's working fine with ['Red', 'Pink', 'Blue'] but it's throwing error when ['Red', 'Pink', 'Blue'], ['Berry', 'Phalai', 'Malta'] parse. any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Okay, that is because it is not allowed to have two top-level values. Also you must use `"` for the values. You can use an online parser to check (for example on [jsonformatter.org](https://jsonformatter.org/json-parser)). You could create two seperate arrays which you `stringify()` or two separate strings which you `parse()`. Or wrap your string with `[]` and take the `[0]` element after parsing.